# Me as openid provider

Tags: openid, google-openid, openid-provider

I have an website which is using openid and I made it as an openid provider.

Is there any possibility to display my openid provider in other openid provider website as an identity provider as google,Yahoo,etc.,

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways do to thing:

1. Either request the code providers to set the your app also in the main list. e.g. stackoverflow request to admin or request the developers you are giving the free code for using openid
2. You create your own utility and try to distribute among developers by using GIT or CVS as it will boost the automatically as one of your website as provider website.

There is no other ways else your website become so much popular to be one of it.